# Replace set /p line in batch?

Tags: batch

I have a script that asks for user input with the command `set /p msg="Enter Message>"` Which works fine but I was wondering if I could have it then remove the line it had created with the set command.

 current output after set:

```
Hello there
My name is Bob
Enter Message> 1234
great 1234
```

Desired output after set:

```
Hello there
My name is Bob
great 1234
```

Comment: i don't think you can delete 1 line from console that was printed out, but you can do empty prompt or cls to fully clear screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do that using `CLS`. Though we can print another message on same line in some cases. But I am not sure if it can be done after pressing `ENTER` key on user input.

If you want to overwrite same line without user input, you may look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1166580/overwrite-line-in-windows-batch-file/1166728#1166728) question.

I used two input and output just to check if it is working as expected. So, added another line in sample output you have provided.

Here is batch file created for two user inputs.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET UserInput1Done=0
SET UserInput2Done=0
:Start
CLS
ECHO Hello there
ECHO My name is Bob
IF %UserInput1Done%==0 (
    SET /P msg1="Enter Message 1>"
    SET UserInput1Done=1
    GOTO Start
)
ECHO great %msg1%
IF %UserInput2Done%==0 (
    SET /P msg2="Enter Message 2>"
    SET UserInput2Done=1
    GOTO Start
)
ECHO great %msg2%
```

Here is output of above batch file.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I need to avoid cls so this wont work. However I like your thinking and Its the best Im going to get I think so I'll accept it.