# Clear Windows Terminal + cmd.exe from .bat file

Tags: windows, terminal, batch-file, windows-terminal

I am using [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) along with a batch file that runs `cls` as the first command. Under standalone `cmd.exe` running `cls` clears the window and scrollback. Under Windows Terminal, it does not clear the scrollback.

What can I add to my .bat file along with `cls` to remove the scrollback?

[This bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1305) claims that using `echo "$([char]27)[2J$([char]27)[3J"` clears the scrollback, but I believe that this applies to either Ubuntu host or Powershell. If I put that command verbatim into the .bat file it just echoes those literal characters.

Comment: [Ansi escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are also supported in cmd, you just have to enter the 0x1b / dec 27  character into your batch file, not all editors are able to enter those. A [workaround using certutil.exe](https://superuser.com/a/1166644/639112)

Comment: Are you saying that `$([char]27)` represents a literal ASCII Escape character, and that's all I need to change?

Comment: Exactly. `ESC`[2J`ESC`3J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments by @LotPings you can do this if you can type an ASCII escape character (code 27) into your batch file.

`@cls && echo ␛[2J␛[3J`

That is what `$([char]27)` was doing in my original question. Unfortunately, most web browsers will strip these if I paste them in a code block. The ␛ character seen above is not ASCII 27, but indicates where that character needs to be.

If you can run this JavaScript code, you can copy the result and paste into a `.bat` file.

```js
alert("@cls && echo "+String.fromCharCode(27,91,50,74,27,91,51,75))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this to work in Terminal:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\08\29\SO_1476288.cmd
:: Since windows 10 Treshold2 the console understands  
:: [Ansi Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)  
:: These codes require the escape char hex 0x1b or decimal 27 which is  
:: difficult to generate (depends on your editor)  
::  
::     esc [ 2  J  esc [ 3  J
:: hex 1B 5B 32 4A 1B 5B 33 4A
::
:: This Batch uses certutil to decode a hex string to ascii here
@echo off
echo 1B 5B 32 4A 1B 5B 33 4A>Clear.hex
Del Clear.bin
certutil -decodehex Clear.hex Clear.bin >NUL 2>&1
Set /P Clear=<Clear.bin

dir
Timeout /t 3 >Nul
Echo %Clear%
```