# Hide all text in cmd window, except the last line?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

---

My question is how would I hide all text above the last line?
Somehow delete the text of the first part and then only show an echo of the last line - that still has user input functionality though.

```
[=  ]
[== ]
[===]
"last line with any text" (Y/N)?
```

Is there any rule I could add to a batch command that would show only the last line of the current command text result in the window?

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem, you want to hide all text then why you will display them using `echo`?

Comment: Ok, my first example was a bit misleading and I removed it. My question is just about how to hide everything that is not the last line.

Comment: Then append `>nul 2>&1` to each `echo` lines you want to hide.

Comment: you probably asking for [ANSI escape sequences](https://www.computerhope.com/ansisys.htm#escape) cursor movement how to erase line

Comment: You posted this exact question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use cmd and use powershell instead. [`Get-Content` cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) (and its aliases `cat` and `gc`) has a `Tail` option to do this

```powershell
Get-Content file_path -Tail 1
```

If the text is the result of another command then use [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) or its `select` alias

```powershell
your_command | Select-Object -Last 1
```

If you really need to use cmd then run the command from PowerShell like this

```powershell
powershell -Com "gc file_path -Tail 1"
powershell -Com "your_command | select -Last 1"
```

If you have some kind of POSIX environments on your system wsl/wsl2 or cygwin then just use [`tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html):

```bsh
cat file | tail -n 1
your_command | tail -n 1
tail file -n 1
```

See also

- [Unix tail equivalent command in Windows Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4426442/995714)

Answer (score 0):

- To delete/remove used lines you can use the solution from **[@LotPings](https://superuser.com/users/639112/lotpings)** in this **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1476789/969781)**, in additional, you also can use this in base64 decoded by Certutil

```all-bat
@echo off 

title <nul && title Q1575583

call %:^0 && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%L in (1 1 4)do echo\Line 0%%L

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 >nul 
type "%temp%\_bs.bin" 
type "%temp%\_bs.bin" 

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 >nul 
echo/Line 06

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 >nul 
type "%temp%\_bs.bin" 

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 >nul 
echo/Line 07

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 >nul 
type "%temp%\_bs.bin" 

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 >nul
type "%temp%\_bs.bin" 

2>nul del/Q /F "%temp%\_bs.bin" 
endlocal & goto=:EOF

%:^0
>nul 2>&1 del /q /f "%temp%\_bs.bin"
>nul 2>&1 "%__APPDIR__%Certutil.exe" -decode -f "%~f0" "%temp%\_bs.bin" & exit /b
:: <-----BEGIN .\_bs.bin ----- G1sxRhtbMEobWzFGG1swSg0K== -----END .\_bs.bin -----> ::
```

- Outputs:

[image]

- About the strings in Base64 in this bat/cmd decoded in file `"%temp%\_bs.bin"`

[image]