# How to read files name last character and and rename them by running a batch file

Tags: batch, rename, ms-dos, characters, read

I have 3 files in a folder which are:

```
XXX_a.txt
XXX_b.txt
XXX_c.txt
```

The filename can be **varied**, only the last character of the 3 files
**`a`**, **`b`** and **`c`** are not changed

I need to rename the files as below:

```
XXX_a.txt to first.log
XXX_b.txt to second.log
XXX_c.txt to third.log
```

How to write a batch file to read each file's name last character and then rename it respectively?

Your help are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename using wildcards:

```
rename *_a.txt first.log
rename *_b.txt second.log
rename *_c.txt third.log
```

This assumes there's only a single _a, _b and _c file.

Comment: Thank you Berend for your kind and fast response, that what's I need, you're the best! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

- This answer is intended to show how you can rename your files using batch loops and console executable in **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** compiled at run time by **[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)** itself
- Where programmatically the repetition of the command will be in charge of assigning the names to your files already comprising a range of scope **`*_[a-z-0-9]`**

- Two options are provided in this example, name them cardinally or literally:

- Also designed to prevent errors from occurring if there is more than one file with the same letter:
- Also preventing the occurrence of errors if there is more than one file with the same letter:

```all-bat-file
XXX_a.txt First.log
YYY_a.txt Second.log
XXX_b.txt Third.log
YYY_b.txt Fourth.log
XXX_c.txt Fifth.log
YYY_c.txt Sixth.log
```

- The **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code is adapted from this **[post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-numeric-value-into-words-currency-in-c-sharp)** by **[RAFNAS TP](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/members/rafnas-t-p)**
- The command line used to compile with `csc.exe`:

```all-bat-file
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -w:0 -unsafe+ -codepage:1252 -t:exe -platform:anycpu -out:"Q1594189_Cardinal.exe" "Q1594189_Cardinal.cmd" -o -nologo

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe -w:0 -unsafe+ -codepage:1252 -t:exe -platform:anycpu -out:"Q1594189_Literal.exe" "Q1594189_Literal.cmd" -o -nologo
```

- The following `csc.exe` compilers were used/tested [Windows 10 pro 2004]:

```all-bat-file
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

- You can check for available csc.exe version in your command line using:

```all-bat-file
>for /f tokens^=* %c in ('where /r %windir%\Microsoft.NET csc.exe^|findstr.exe /i k.*v')do @echo\%c

rem :: returns/outputs :: 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

- This script automatically deletes the files generated on execution

```all-bat-file
del/q /f "%tmp%\_bs.bin" "!_path!\%~n0.exe"
```

- File **`"%tmp%\_bs.bin"`** is generated by decoding strings in base64 to delete 2 lines above, removing the escaping used to mark comments in **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)**

```all-bat-file
/* 2>nul || @echo off
```

[image]

- **Obs.:** String source from **[@LotPings](https://superuser.com/users/639112/lotpings)** in this **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1476789/969781)**
- File **`"!_path!\%~n0.exe"`** is the same **`path\Q1594189_Cardinal.exe`** or **`"path\Q1594189_Literal.exe"`** is respectively the name of the executable, obtained at run time, where **`%~n0`** is the name of the used bat name concatenated with **`.exe`**, forming **`my_file.bat`** ==>> **`my_file.exe`**
- The exeucatel file generated on execution accepts 1 numeric argument (int) and returns the corresponding cardinal or literal string respectively:

```all-bat-file
C:\>Q1594189_Cardinal.exe 11 
Eleventh

C:\>Q1594189_Literal.exe 11
Eleven
```

- To keep one of these files just remove it from the `del` command:

```all-bat-file
del/q /f "%tmp%\_bs.bin" "!_path!\%~n0.exe"

del/q /f "%tmp%\_bs.bin" "!_path!\%~n0.exe"
```

- To keep both, just remove the `del` command, and the existence of one or both files does not interfere with the main execution:

```all-bat-file
del/q /f "%tmp%\_bs.bin" "!_path!\%~n0.exe"
```

- It has also been tested and works with only 3 files...

---

**<kbd>.\Q1594189_Literal.cmd :</kbd>**

```all-bat-file
/* 2>nul || @echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" && title <nul && title ...\%~nx0
call %:^) && cd /d "%~dp0" && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
<con: echo\ && set "_path=!cd!" && pushd %__APPDIR__% && color 0a

set "_flag_c#=-w:0 -unsafe+ -codepage:1252 -t:exe -platform:anycpu" 
set "_flag_c#=!_flag_c#! -out:"!_path!\%~n0.exe" "!_path!\%~nx0" -o -nologo"

for /f tokens^=* %%c in ('where /r ..\Microsoft.NET csc.exe^|findstr.exe /i k.v4
')do <con: cmd.exe /v:on /e:on /s /c ""%%~c" !_flag_c#!" && goto %:^] || goto %:^V

%:^V
timeout.exe /t -1 | echo\ Something's really wrong here^!!. && type "%tmp%\_bs.bin"
<con: ^< nul del/q /f "%tmp%\_bs.bin" "%~dpn0.exe" 2>nul & popd & endlocal & goto :EOF

%:^)
2>nul "%__APPDIR__%Certutil.exe" -decode -f "%~dpnx0" "%temp%\_bs.bin" >nul || goto %:^v
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('type "%temp%\_bs.bin"')do set "_bs=%%~i" && echo\%%~i && exit /b
rem :: <-----BEGIN ...\_bs.bin ----- G1sxRhtbMEobWzFGG1swSg0K== -----END ...\_bs.bin -----> :: 

%:^]
set "_cnt=0" && set "_range=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
for %%A in (!_range!)do for /f eol^=^|delims^= %%G in ('2^>nul %__APPDIR__%where.exe "!_path!:*_%%~A.txt"
')do set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('"!_path!\%~n0.exe" !_cnt!')do <con: rename "%%~G" "%%~i.log" 

timeout.exe -1|echo\Is done^^!!. & 2>nul del/q /f "%tmp%\_bs.bin" "!_path!\%~n0.exe" & popd & endlocal & goto:EOF

rem :: --------------- This C# code is adapted from original RAFNAS TP post in c-sharpcorner.com ::   
rem :: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-numeric-value-into-words-currency-in-c-sharp :: */ 

using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 1)
        {
            string number = args[0].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(Program.Tens(number)));
        }
    }

    private static String Tens(String number)
    {
        int _number = Convert.ToInt32(number);
        String name = null;
        switch (_number)
        {
            case 1:  
                name = "One";  
                break;  
            case 2:  
                name = "Two";  
                break;  
            case 3:  
                name = "Three";  
                break;  
            case 4:  
                name = "Four";  
                break;  
            case 5:  
                name = "Five";  
                break;  
            case 6:  
                name = "Six";  
                break;  
            case 7:  
                name = "Seven";  
                break;  
            case 8:  
                name = "Eight";  
                break;  
            case 9:  
                name = "Nine";  
                break; 
            case 10:
                name = "Ten";
                break;
            case 11:
                name = "Eleven";
                break;
            case 12:
                name = "Twelve";
                break;
            case 13:
                name = "Thirteen";
                break;
            case 14:
                name = "Fourteen";
                break;
            case 15:
                name = "Fifteen";
                break;
            case 16:
                name = "Sixteen";
                break;
            case 17:
                name = "Seventeen";
                break;
            case 18:
                name = "Eighteen";
                break;
            case 19:
                name = "Nineteen";
                break;
            case 20:
                name = "Twenty";
                break;
            case 30:
                name = "Thirty";
                break;
            case 40:
                name = "Fourty";
                break;
            case 50:
                name = "Fifty";
                break;
            case 60:
                name = "Sixty";
                break;
            case 70:
                name = "Seventy";
                break;
            case 80:
                name = "Eighty";
                break;
            case 90:
                name = "Ninety";
                break;
                
            default:
                if (_number > 0)
                {
                    name = Tens(number.Substring(0, 1) + "0") + " " + Tens(number.Substring(1));
                }
                break;
        }
        return name;
    }        
}
```

---

**<kbd>.\Q1594189_Cardial.cmd :</kbd>**

```all-bat-file
/* 2>nul || @echo off

cd /d "%~dp0" && title <nul && title ...\%~nx0
call %:^) && cd /d "%~dp0" && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
<con: echo\ && set "_path=!cd!" && pushd %__APPDIR__% && color 0a

set "_flag_c#=-w:0 -unsafe+ -codepage:1252 -t:exe -platform:anycpu" 
set "_flag_c#=!_flag_c#! -out:"!_path!\%~n0.exe" "!_path!\%~nx0" -o -nologo"

for /f tokens^=* %%c in ('where /r ..\Microsoft.NET csc.exe^|findstr.exe /i k.v4
')do <con: cmd.exe /v:on /e:on /s /c ""%%~c" !_flag_c#!" && goto %:^] || goto %:^V

%:^V
timeout.exe /t -1 | echo\ Something's really wrong here^!!. && type "%tmp%\_bs.bin"
<con: ^< nul del/q /f "%tmp%\_bs.bin" "%~dpn0.exe" 2>nul & popd & endlocal & goto :EOF

%:^)
2>nul "%__APPDIR__%Certutil.exe" -decode -f "%~dpnx0" "%temp%\_bs.bin" >nul || goto %:^v
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('type "%temp%\_bs.bin"')do set "_bs=%%~i" && echo\%%~i && exit /b
rem :: <-----BEGIN ...\_bs.bin ----- G1sxRhtbMEobWzFGG1swSg0K== -----END ...\_bs.bin -----> :: 

%:^]
set "_cnt=0" && set "_range=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
for %%A in (!_range!)do for /f eol^=^|delims^= %%G in ('2^>nul %__APPDIR__%where.exe "!_path!:*_%%~A.txt"
')do set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('"!_path!\%~n0.exe" !_cnt!')do "<con: rename "%%~G" "%%~i.log" 

timeout.exe -1|echo\Is done^^!!. & 2>nul del/q /f "%tmp%\_bs.bin" "!_path!\%~n0.exe" & popd & endlocal & goto:EOF

rem :: --------------- This C# code is adapted from original RAFNAS TP post in c-sharpcorner.com ::   
rem :: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-numeric-value-into-words-currency-in-c-sharp :: */ 
 
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 1)
        {
            string number = args[0].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(Program.Tens(number)));
        }
    }

    private static String Tens(String number)
    {
        int _number = Convert.ToInt32(number);
        String name = null;
        switch (_number)
        {
                case 1:
                name = "First";
                break;
                case 2:
                name = "Second";
                break;
                case 3:
                name = "Third";
                break;
                case 4:
                name = "Fourth";
                break;
                case 5:
                name = "Fifth";
                break;
                case 6:
                name = "Sixth";
                break;
                case 7:
                name = "Seventh";
                break;
                case 8:
                name = "Eighth";
                break;
                case 9:
                name = "Ninth";
                break;
                case 10:
                name = "Tenth";
                break;
                case 11:
                name = "Eleventh";
                break;
                case 12:
                name = "Twelfth";
                break;
                case 13:
                name = "Thirteenth";
                break;
                case 14:
                name = "Fourteenth";
                break;
                case 15:
                name = "Fifteenth";
                break;
                case 16:
                name = "Sixteenth";
                break;
                case 17:
                name = "Seventeenth";
                break;
                case 18:
                name = "Eighteenth";
                break;
                case 19:
                name = "Nineteenth";
                break;
                case 20:
                name = "Twentieth";
                break;
                case 30:
                name = "Fhirtieth";
                break;
                case 40:
                name = "Fortieth";
                break;
                case 50:
                name = "Fiftieth";
                break;
                case 60:
                name = "Sixtieth";
                break;
                case 70:
                name = "Seventieth";
                break;
                case 80:
                name = "Eightieth";
                break;
                case 90:
                name = "Ninetieth";
                break;
                
                default:
                if (_number > 0)
                {
                    name = Tens(number.Substring(0, 1) + "0") + " " + Tens(number.Substring(1));
                }
                break;
        }
        return name;
    }        
}
```

---

- Some further reading for cmd/bat files:

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[For loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

  [√] **[For /F loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Goto | :label](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)**

  [√] **[DOS Tips substrings](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

  [√] **[Command line building with csc.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe)**