# Error using escape sequences with ANSICON .EXE - I'm getting: 's not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows-10, batch

This is my batch file:

```bat
ansicon -p

[0;30;4;40mThis is a sentence.[0;1;31;40mThis is a sentence too.
  
pause
```

With **`@echo off`** in the batch file I'm only seeing:

```bat
's not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

With **`@echo on`** I'm seeing:

```bat
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Aranesp_injection_reminder\ANSICON>ansicon -p

C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Aranesp_injection_reminder\ANSICON>This is a sentence.This is a sentence too.

's not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Obs.:** Using **`0x1b`** for the **<kbd>ESC</kbd>** character.

Comment: To show something on the screen, you have to use echo command.  Otherwise it is trying to execute your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> *Using **`0x1b`** for the **<kbd>ESC</kbd>** character.*
>
> - Use **<kbd>ESC</kbd>** saved in variable

---

- In your batch file:

```bat
@echo off

color 0a

for /f skip^=4 %%b in ('"echo;prompt;$E|cmd"')do set "_esc=%%b"

echo/%_esc%[0;30;4;40mThis is a sentence. %_esc%[0;1;31;40mThis is a sentence too

timeout 3 >nul & color f0
```

---

- In your command-line:

```bat
for /f skip^=4 %b in ('"echo;prompt;$E|cmd"')do @echo\ %b[0;30;4;40mThis is a sentence.%b[0;1;31;40m. This is a sentence too & timeout 3 >nul & color f0
```

---

**[ANSI Escape Sequences](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)**

**[Use ANSI colors in the terminal](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-ansi.html)**

**[`Tetris.BAT`](https://github.com/Honguito98/batch-game-flappy-bird/blob/master/Flappy_Bird.bat)** by **[@Aacini](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6812)**

- **[Tetris game in a pure Batch file](https://github.com/Honguito98/batch-game-flappy-bird/blob/master/Flappy_Bird.bat)**

**[`Flappy_Bird.bat`](https://github.com/yutsunoki/Flappy_Bird_With_Batch_File)**

- **[Using ANSI Code in game in bat file](https://github.com/yutsunoki/Flappy_Bird_With_Batch_File)**

**[`Pacman_kinda.bat`](https://github.com/IcarusLivesHF/Batch-Script-Projects/blob/main/Pacman_kinda.bat)**

- **[Another sample fo Using ANSI Code in game in bat file](https://github.com/IcarusLivesHF/Batch-Script-Projects/blob/main/Pacman_kinda.bat)**

**[`Library.bat` Revision 4.1.0](https://github.com/IcarusLivesHF/Windows-Batch-Library/blob/8812670566744d2ee14a9a68a06be333a27488cc/Library.bat)**

- **[The Window Batch Library // Documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IcarusLivesHF/Windows-Batch-Library/master/documentation.bat)**

**[Search for *"Bat Games"*](https://www.dostips.com/forum/search.php?keywords=games)** on **[DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/)**

- **[Many examples using **ANSI Codes**](https://www.dostips.com/forum/search.php?keywords=games)**

Comment: Is ANSICON.EXE not needed in Windows 10? I would still like to know how to use the program. Even when I use it in the following way - I get allot of these messages i.e 's not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Viz: ansicon.exe -p C:\Users\Admin\TEST\colors.bat - where color.bat contains entries like this:  [0;30;40m                [0m  [0;1;30;40m                [0m  [0;30;4;40m                [0m  [0;1;30;4;40m                [0m

Comment: No, ansicon.exe is not required.

Comment: OKAY thank you for that! i haven't found any versatile examples using ASCICON - only how to install and de-install the program. Is there a site that shows allot of examples using ANSICON? Are using ANSI escapes sequences easier to use with ASCICON  or not?

Comment: Try looking specifically for ***using ansi code*** and not how to use a *program that uses ansi code*. You can see an example [without using ansicon.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/1718940/how-to-clear-message-sent-by-echo-command/1719889#1719889)

Comment: Do I need to have VirtualTerminalLevel as a DWORD set to 0x1 in Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console to use ANSI escapes sequences?? I will not be using ANSICON.exe anymore.

Comment: No need, my windows doesn't even have that entry in my registry.