# How can I put 2 different texts of 1 color each in a BAT file?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

How can I put 2 different texts of 1 color each? Because when I tried to put, for example `//` color B to a text and then I put color A to another text, I took color A, which was the code below and the one I took:

CODE:

[image]

.BAT:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use ANSI escape codes, as were used in terminals and printers. There's an excellent demo [batch file at GitHub](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011/raw/b710612d6320df7e146508094e84b92b34c77d48/win10colors.cmd). View it in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or other code editor to see special characters, such as ASCII(27), ESC. BTW, add a `pause` for the last line, or the command prompt showing the output will quickly disappear.

For example, in a .bat file, enter `echo ▼[31mRed▼[0m`, where the triangle, ▼, is meant to be <kbd>ESC</kbd> to see the word in red letters. In Notepad++, that can be entered from the *Character Panel* (or Windows *Character Map* or [BabelMap](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html):

[image: Notepad++ Character Panel]

Note that the string `<ESC>[31m` sets text after it to red, and `<ESC>[0m` resets text color to default.

Comment: I tried to do something like this, but for some reason in my code the red [] appear as if something was wrong in the code and in my .bat it shows the same as in the code

I'm trying to change just the color of the brackets

https://imgur.com/a/s2rCanZ

https://imgur.com/a/kPRLAlk

Comment: The pic looked OK, i.e., only brackets were red. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when the red parentheses appear in a code, there is an error and in the other photo you can see that my brackets do not turn blue as they should: [ A ]

something like this would be:

[ ] : Color Cyan

A: Color White

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@(cls & color 1f & cd. & goto %:^))
                   _______  ______    _______  _______  _______        __   __  ____
                  |       ||    _ |  |       ||       ||       |      |  | |  ||    |
                  |    ___||   | ||  |   _   ||  _____||_     _|      |  |_|  | |   |
                  |   |___ |   |_||_ |  | |  || |_____   |   |        |       | |   |
                  |    ___||    __  ||  |_|  ||_____  |  |   |        |       | |   |
                  |   |    |   |  | ||       | _____| |  |   |         |     |  |   |
                  |___|    |___|  |_||_______||_______|  |___|          |___|   |___|

%:^)
@echo off

for /f skip^=4 %%e in ('echo;prompt $E^|cmd.exe')do set "_$E=%%~e"
title <nul & title %_$E% SuperUser %_$E% Q1826937 & mode con lines=16 cols=104

findstr.exe /e "_ |" "%~f0" & echo/ & pathping 127.1 -n -q 1 -p 1500 >nul 2>nul & color

timeout /t 02 | echo\ %_$e%[0;30;32;40mThis is a sentence with %_$e%[0;1;4;34;40mcolor A%_$e%[0m & echo/
timeout /t 02 | echo/ %_$e%[0;30;32;40mThis is a sentence with %_$e%[0;1;4;31;40mcolor B%_$e%[0m & echo\
timeout /t 02 | echo\ %_$e%[0;30;32;40mThis is a sentence with %_$e%[0;1;4;34;40mcolor A%_$e%[0;30;32;40m and %_$e%[0;1;4;31;40mcolor B%_$e%[0m & echo\
```

---

[image]

---

You can get the ESC as a variable if you prefer, so regardless of the text editor, you have options for inserting this type of character and composing your lines following the different color options and [formatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), also the limitations relevant to the versions/systems.

---

Maybe you might also be interested in:
***[How to clear message sent by echo command](https://superuser.com/questions/1718940/how-to-clear-message-sent-by-echo-command/1719889#1719889)***