# Condense repetitive stdout output into one line

Tags: batch-file

I have a tool that is called from a batch file that prints many lines of repetitive output, like

> 1 row created.
>
> 1 row created.
>
> 1 row created.
>
> 1 row deleted.
>
> 1 row deleted.
>
> Format is unknown, row will omitted.
>
> 1 row created.
>
> 1 row created.
>
> 1 file created.
>
> 1 file created.
>
> 1 file created.
>
> 1 file deleted.
>
> 1 file deleted.
>
> Tool has finished successfully.

and so on, except that there can be literally thousands of identical lines. In this way the output in the terminal window is pretty much useless. Of course I could redirect it and write all of it to a file and then proceed with that, but I would like to be able to see at a glance what has happened and is happening. Is there a way to manipulate the stream in the batch file that is calling this tool so that the output looks like

> (3x) 1 row created.
>
> (2x) 1 row deleted.
>
> (1x) Format is unknown, row will omitted.
>
> (2x) 1 row created.
>
> (3x) 1 file created.
>
> (2x) 1 file deleted.
>
> (1x) Tool has finished successfully.

Preferrably the the counter in the currently last line would update in place (replacing the old value) and increase each time an output line is repeated, so one would also get a feeling for the progress made so far.

**Edit:** Some research yielded some parts that seem useful for this task:

1. [This answer shows how to read from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6980605/5612244)
2. [Here it is shown how to replace the current line in Terminal, so we can have just the counter increasing](https://superuser.com/a/492067/823373)
3. [Articel about using functions in batch](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-7-functions.html), which seems a good way to keep the stream editing part separate from the other parts of the file.